# How to open a project in PhpStorm using command line

Tags: phpstorm

I am using **Git** Command Line, Homestead, Windows 10, PhpStorm 2017.3.

I want to open any project in PhpStorm using git bash /command line.

Comment: That either won't work or will be a whole lot of work. PHPStorm generates a lot of it's own files when you open a project (like the .idea folder), also it generates some xml files, indexes the project ... there is no way to do all this via the command line. That's a project in itself.

Comment: Not properly helpful answer . by the way , thanks for comment

Answer (score 6):

Just pass **FULL path to the project root folder** as parameter to PhpStorm executable file -- IDE will either open existing project (if `.idea` subfolder exist) or will create brand new project from those files.

It works the same as if you would use `Open` from within PhpStorm and point to such folder.

An example:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm\bin\phpstorm64.exe" "C:\Projects\MyProject"
```

- `phpstorm64.exe` is for 64-bit Java
- For 32-bit Java you should use `phpstorm.exe`

---

You can add path to PhpStorm executable into system's `PATH` variable so there will be no need to use the full path. But then you have to install new versions into the same folder or update `PATH` as needed. The you could just use `phpstorm64.exe "C:\Projects\MyProject"`.

You can also create some alias/batch file (similar idea to what Mac/Linux user have -- there IDE creates that for them) so it's easier to use. It's a bit more initial work but easier to keep the path up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify another path for your program but if nothing else just use this I guess.
[image]